# Angular .then undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am trying to implement [this promise pattern](https://youtu.be/hf1T_AONQJU?t=34m44s) in an Angularjs app. But `someUserContent` returns the value `true` not the actual data as desired. How do I get the data to the controller?

In my controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl',function() {

   MyFactory.checkUser(userId) //returns true
   .then(MyFactory.prepDatabase())  //returns true
   .then(Myfactory.getUserContent()) //returns a someUserData
   .then(function(someUserData) {
       //do some stuff with all this data  
    });
}
```

And the factory:

```
.factory('MyFactory', function($q,$http....) {

   MyFactory.prototype.checkUser = function(user_id) {
      var self = this;
      this.db = new PouchDB('users', {location: 'default'});   
      return $q.when(true);
   }

   Myfactory.prototype.getUserContent = function() {
    if (!self.someUserData) {
      return $q.when(self.db.allDocs({ include_docs: true}))
        .then(function(docs) { 
          self.someUserData = docs.rows.map(function(row) {
            return row.doc;
          });
          return $q.when(self.someUserData);
        })
    } else {
      return $q.when(self.someUserData);
    }
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass reference instead of invoking methods. You are making async call and it need to wait for promise has returned, when you are executing them inside then method they don't have promise that's why you are getting error.

```
 .then(MyFactory.prepDatabase) 
   .then(Myfactory.getUserContent)
```

and change your factory

```
.factory('MyFactory', function($q,$http....) {
 var db = new PouchDB('users', {location: 'default'});
   MyFactory.prototype.checkUser = function(user_id) {
      var self = this;             
      return $q.when(true);
   }

   Myfactory.prototype.getUserContent = function() {
    if (!self.someUserData) {
      return $q.when(db.allDocs({ include_docs: true}))
        .then(function(docs) { 
          self.someUserData = docs.rows.map(function(row) {
            return row.doc;
          });
          return $q.when(self.someUserData);
        })
    } else {
      return $q.when(self.someUserData);
    }
   }    
}
```

Comment: If I do this, `.then(Myfactory.getUserContent) ` generates the error `Cannot read property 'allDocs' of null`

Comment: self.db does not exists in getUserContent, try to make youre db available in the whole factory
this.db = new PouchDB('users', {location: 'default'});

Comment: Doesn't `var self = this;` take care of that issue? Changing to `this.db` did not resolve the error.

Comment: you declared this in checkUset context and it's available only there, i updated my answer try it.

Comment: Thanks I tried your answer and `allDocs` is still null

Comment: then something is with your db your original query regarding .then undefined is resolved i think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120882/discussion-between-mrjsingh-and-lilbiscuit).